# Python descriptors set and get behaviour

Tags: python, descriptor, setattribute, getattribute, setattr

Say, we put two different descriptors in a class, and then check how they work being requested from an instance and a class itself.

```py
class DescrGet:
    def __get__(self, instance, typ):
        print("DescrGet")

class DescrSet:
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("DescrSet")

class A:
    descr_get = DescrGet()
    descr_set = DescrSet()
```

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> a.descr_get
DescrGet
>>> a.descr_set = 42
DescrSet
>>> A.descr_get
DescrGet
>>> A.descr_set = 42
>>> print(A.descr_set)
42
```

Seems like quite inconsistent behaviour.
From python docs page about [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), I get the basic concepts of how python looks up for requested attribute. But it says nothing about setting an atribute.
Here, after searching in `type(A).__dict__` (finds nothing of course) python continues to search in `A.__dict__` for descriptor and when successfully finds it, calls `__get__` method but (surprisingly) doesn't call `__set__` and simply sets `A.a` to 42.

Could someone provide explanation for such behaviour or give any links?